# ubuntu touch split screen

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am using Ubuntu touch (OTA 12) on my BQ M10. When using the split screen mode, the apps are adjusting to the small potion of the screen while the apps are not adjusting to the bigger part of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure wjat you are trying to ask here. However, i have experienced a bit of an issue with trying to move the open apps from the side panel into tje main screen. I have overcome this in the past by closing the app down and opening it again. However, in the latest build i have noticed that moving of apps is slightly easier. Tapping on the main screen with three fingers, three times brings the side panel uo.